# NullPointer with an EditText only on android v4

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, search-box

I made a little app for android tablets v3 in mind back in the day. It was working just fine until I decided to test it on android v4. The problem comes from a search box that is placed at the action bar at the top of the fragment layout. On android 3.x it just loads fine and works like a charm but that's not the case on android 4.x, everytime I load the fragment the app crashes.

```
I/System.out(8863): v3: android.widget.EditText@40a34fa8
I/System.out(28353): v4: null
```

I know I am possibily not inflating the object or layout somewhere for the android 4.x "standards" but I just can´t figure where the problem is.

Here is the logcat:

```
01-24 12:31:41.527: I/System.out(28353): v4: null
01-24 12:31:41.527: D/AndroidRuntime(28353): Shutting down VM
01-24 12:31:41.527: W/dalvikvm(28353): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bc41f8)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at prob_test665.prob_test.FragmentListMenuSEARCH.ifcSEARCH(FragmentListMenuSEARCH.java:154)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at prob_test665.prob_test.FragmentListMenuSEARCH.onPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentListMenuSEARCH.java:115)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1865)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2463)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:438)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:761)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2552)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.invalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1914)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:898)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at prob_test665.prob_test.FragmentListMenuSEARCH.onCreateView(FragmentListMenuSEARCH.java:57)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at prob_test665.prob_test.ccc_frament.onCreateView(ccc_frament.java:68)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-24 12:31:41.535: E/AndroidRuntime(28353):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are pieces of code

at prob_test665.prob_test.FragmentListMenuSEARCH.ifcSEARCH(FragmentListMenuSEARCH.java:154)

```
EditText text_search = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_search);
```

That is the line where the app crash when I load the fragment. Tried to replace getActivity with context, dialog.. but no luck.

There are the two pieces of code from a test I made just to make it bit more clear:

http://pastebin.com/ZwVJCduE

http://pastebin.com/ZePzctke

Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT: Forgot the xml for the bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/item_search" android:actionLayout="@layout/search_box" android:showAsAction="always" android:visible="false"></item>

    <item android:title="test55" android:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>

            <item 
                android:id="@+id/subitem_m_sinc"
                android:title="@string/item_m_sinc2"
                android:titleCondensed="@string/item_m_sinc1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

            <item 
                android:id="@+id/subitem_m_ord"
                android:title="@string/item_me_ord"/>

            <item 
                android:id="@+id/subitem_m_ccc"
                android:title="@string/item_m_ccc"/>

            <item 
                android:id="@+id/subitem_m_config"
                android:title="@string/item_m_config"/>

        </menu>

    </item>
```